# Xcode 6.1 crashing when I try to run my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

I'm using XCode Version 6.1.1 (6A2008a)
It crashes very frequently. It suddenly disaapears when I try to run the program. It crashes without giving error message. When I try to run it again and again it runs some how at some point. Also there is no error log entry about it when I check it via console.
It doesn't matter if it's deployed in simulator or real device.
I mailed the situation to Apple support but I couldn't get an answer.

Is there any idea how to solve the problem. Thanks for advance.

Comment: Are you running Xcode in full screen? Mine had the same problem and when I exited out of full screen it worked fine.

Comment: Yes I'm using it full screen. I'm trying your advice now

Comment: I was doing this using a terminal application. But, I feel like the same applies with an iOS application.

Comment: It does have some crashing bugs. I often crash just by switching to Xcode and clicking in code! But Apple gets the crash reports, so I'm sure they know about it. There's nothing you can do; just save a lot!

Comment: I exited out of full screen. It stopped crashing. Then I switched to full screen mode again. It's not crashing for a while. I'm watching it.

Comment: In the mean time, I will add it as an answer so that way you can mark it if solved.

Comment: Ok, I'll let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this problem too when I use the Run button to launch a test. 
The bug is on this button, then I use CMD+R and it never happens.

I think the problem is when you click on the Run button, I don't know why, Xcode think you've clicked on the Close button (the red one).

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar situation when trying to run a command line tool application in Xcode 6.1.1. I found out that if I exited full screen mode, Xcode would not crash anymore when trying to run the application.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and it was too many old breakpoints tracks, even to deleted files, I just clean it and now it runs perfect, I hope it helps.

A picture to illustrate:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. How odd of Apple/XCode to silently treat it this way.